# What format does the module Struct require?

Tags: python, struct

I faced the module Struct for the first time and my code gives me an error: "unpack requires a buffer of 1486080 bytes"
Here is my code:

```
def speed_up(n):
source = wave.open('sound.wav', mode='rb')
dest = wave.open('out.wav', mode='wb')
dest.setparams(source.getparams())
frames_count = source.getnframes()
data = struct.unpack("<" + str(frames_count) + "h", source.readframes(frames_count))
new_data = []
for i in range(0, len(data), n):
    new_data.append(data[i])
newframes = struct.pack('<' + str(len(new_data)) + 'h', new_data)
dest.writeframes(newframes)
source.close()
dest.close()
```

How to figure out which format should I use?

Comment: Did you check the type and size of the object you're passing to `unpack`?

Comment: @interjay, Yes, I checked it, type - 'bytes', size - '2972193'.
Now I see my mistake - the value of frames_count is  743040, and the format didn't match the buffer. 
I tried to set the format as '<2972193b', but it caused error 'unpack requires a buffer of 2972193 bytes'.
Can you tell me, please, why the buffer size and format size aren't equal in this case?

Comment: That size doesn't make sense to me, because it isn't divisible by 2. The error you got from unpack suggests that it isn't the actual size of the bytes object.

Comment: Sorry, now I got the actual size with 'sys.getsizeof(source.readframes(frames_count))', the size is 33 bytes. But anyway I can't realize, which format should I use.

Comment: `getsizeof` is almost never useful. You can get the actual length of data with `len`. You need to take account of the wav file's sample width (which indicates what format to use in `struct.unpack`, and the channel count (number of samples per frame).

Comment: Unfortunately, it still hasn't work.
Parameters of my wav file: `nchannels=2, sampwidth=2, framerate=44100, nframes=743040, comptype='NONE', compname='not compressed'`.
With `len` I got size my buffer object (`source.readframes(frames_count)`), the size is 2972160 bytes. Then I tried to set the format according to this size as `'<' + 'str(nframes * 2) + 'h'`. It caused the error, "unpack requires a buffer of 2972160 bytes". 
If size of buffer object is 2972160 bytes, why does this error appear?

Comment: If the bytes object has 2972160 bytes then it should work.

Comment: Yes, it finally works, with last format, `'<' + 'str(nframes * 2) + 'h'`. That error appeared, because before the string with `struct.unpack` there was the string `print(len(source.readframes(frames_count)))` (while I was making changes, I used that string to see a size of buffer). When I removed this string, it worked. Thank you for  help and for your patience!

Comment: Could you please answer my last question and tell me, why it didn't work with that string?The function `len` doesn't changes an object, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you're providing `struct.unpack` with the wrong number of bytes. This is because of your usage of the `wave` module: Each frame in a wave file has `getnchannels()` samples, so when calling `readframes(n)` you will get back `n * getnchannels()` samples and this is the number you'd have to pass to `struct.unpack`.

To make your code more robust, you'd also need to look at `getsampwidth()` and use an appropriate format character, but the vast majority of wave files are 16-bit.

In the comments you also mentioned that the code didn't work after adding `print(len(source.readframes(frames_count)))`. You didn't show the full code but I assume this is because you called `readframes` twice without calling `rewind`, so the second call didn't have any more data to return. It would be best to store the result in a variable if you want to use it in multiple lines.